# Does the humeroradial joint move medially/laterally?

Tags: human-anatomy, human-physiology, anatomy, movement, joints

The [humeroradial joint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humeroradial_joint) is a [ball-and-socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_and_socket_joint) joint that, if unrestricted, would allow for movement around all possible axes. However (as succinctly stated from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humeroradial_joint)):

> the annular ligament, by which the head of the radius is bound to the radial notch of the ulna...prevents any separation of the two bones laterally.

As a result of the annular ligament, the proximal radioulnar joint and -- quite honestly -- the humeroulnar joint, the humeroradial joint is considered to be "limited." In other words, the humeroradial joint is typically considered only to be capable of taking part in flexion/extension of the elbow and lateral/medial rotation of the forearm.

However, although no internet/textbook search I've conducted mentions it, I'm wondering **does the humeroradial joint allow *any* movements at all in the frontal plane (i.e., adduction/abduction)?**

Here's a visual:

[image: joint]

It seems unlikely, but at least a slight "jittering" seems possible.

Although just *barely* related, the knee (a [hinge joint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinge_joint)) comes to mind because of its somewhat unexpected (based on classification, not structure) ability to "slightly rotate" when unlocking.

Comment: Adduction is highly unlikely because of the restriction provided by the crest in the articular surface of humerus. Also there are no muscles for voluntary abduction and adduction.